# How to provide chunked download of a movie in Firefox & HTML5?

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, video.js

I have created a very simple webpage with a video-container.
At the server-side I provide a 206-chunked download per megabyte (reporting of the Range-Bytes are correct).

In Chrome this works fine, and Chrome downloads 3 files and -I guess- when its cache empties, it downloads another one.
Chrome requests the file with "Range: 0-", so actually what I should be doing is send the whole file, but I just don't want to do this. (especially for mobile users, I don't want them to start downloading a like 500M file)

Now in Firefox, I notice it only downloads the first file chunk. It never requests the next one.

The question here is: how can I provide chunked video streaming in all browsers?

I understand that I can just choose any Flash movie player out there, but that's not really what I want. Another thing I can do is say "use Chrome only" (in my specific case that's an option), but that's also not really what I like. I like to solve the base issue here...

Thanks!

Comment: Just want to add a note that chunked encoding is quite different than Range-Bytes. Chrome as of now doesn't seem to support chunked encoding. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the brains are in the browser, not the server. The server MUST respond to the browser with the correct result for the request that is being made. If you asks the server for an entire files, and it only returns part, The browser is not required to attempt another request for the rest. The fact chrome does this is unusual, and can not be replied upon. If you need control, you must use a fragmented format like fmp4, and add the logic client side in javascript. look into players like video.js